# Spacers and boost hubs, yes or no?

Tags: mountain-bike, wheels, rotor, boost-spacing

Is it possible or recommended to use spacers to fill the gap left by using 100mm front and 142mm rear hubs on boost frames and forks?

Is it fair to think to add possible 2 x 3mm spacers rear ? 5 + 5 mm spacers front?

How to adjust the rotor / caliper positioning?

Answer (score 2):

There are commercial kits that do exactly this, such as the Problem Solvers ones:
[image]

To be clear, a wheel adapted this way offers none of the advantages of Boost, since the flange spacing remains the same.

While these kits are being sold without any such compunction, it's worth pointing out that they put extra leverage on the hub rotor mounting holes and on the axle. Personally I wouldn't be surprised if there's a scenario where you could get a hub or axle to fail because of this - if you look at some hubs, Hope is what I'm thinking of, you can see there's a very minimal amount of material around the rotor mount. So I'm dubious how universal of a solution these kits really are in that sense.

Comment: Hey Nathan, thanks for the info. Well, yes hope, novatec, superstar have very little material in the rotor area, and on fact they fail as well in normal conditions, sometimes. The adapters idea is all about not buying new wheelsets all the time for all different spacing. I honestly doubt what are the real benefits of Boost.